# Problems when deploying JSF+BootsFaces to OpenShift

Tags: jsf, jboss, openshift, bootsfaces

I'm trying to deploy a JSF app that uses BootsFaces to OpenShift. When I run it on localhost everything works fine, but when I run it on OpenShift it looks like all BootsFaces resources are missing even though I have all the libraries set up.

Here's the jboss log I got from rhc

```
C:\Users\axeli\mytomcatapp>rhc tail -f app-root/logs/jbossews.log -o '-n 30'
RSA 1024 bit CA certificates are loaded due to old openssl compatibility
Mar 21, 2016 7:37:13 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, css/default/panels.css.
Mar 21, 2016 7:37:13 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, css/default/labels.css.
Mar 21, 2016 7:37:13 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, css/default/tooltip.css.
Mar 21, 2016 7:37:13 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, css/default/bsf.css.
Mar 21, 2016 7:37:13 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, css/default/jq.ui.core.css.
Mar 21, 2016 7:37:13 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, css/default/jq.ui.theme.css.
Mar 21, 2016 7:37:13 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, css/default/jq.ui.datepicker.css.
Mar 21, 2016 7:37:13 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, css/icons.css.
Mar 21, 2016 7:37:13 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, jq/jquery.js.
Mar 21, 2016 7:37:13 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, jq/ui/core.js.
Mar 21, 2016 7:37:13 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, js/tooltip.js.
Mar 21, 2016 7:37:13 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, jq/ui/datepicker.js.
Mar 21, 2016 7:37:13 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, jq/ui/i18n/datepicker-en.js.
Mar 21, 2016 7:37:13 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, js/bsf.js.
Mar 21, 2016 7:37:13 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, js/collapse.js.
```

My libraries:

[image: Project libraries]

Cartridges:

- Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0)
- MySQL 5.5
- phpMyAdmin 4.0

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Already solved it.
I decompressed BootsFaces jar and copied all the resources to my project's resources folder. Not sure if it's the best solution, because if I upgrade or try to change BootsFaces version I would have to change all of these files.
But for the moment, it's solved.

Comment: Strange. Maybe the resource loading mechanism of JBoss EWS 2.0 is different from the resource loading mechanism of other application servers? Or is the theme declaration missing in the web.xml? In any case, keep us informed if you find out something new! Thanks in advance.